What are possible problems of using dtplyr::lazy_dt()?
I like the syntax of the tidyverse packages dplyr, tidyr and purrr. On the other hand, the data.table packages is very efficient. So there is dtplyr which combines the effeciency of data.table with the familiar dplyr syntax (some benchmarks). If I get it right, all we need to do is
data %>% dtplyr::lazy_dt(.) %>%
... # some code

That is so easy that I wonder why dtplyr is no big thing. There are 37,144 questions about dplyr but only 47 about dtplyr on SO. Or does this mean that dtplyr::lazy_dt() runs so reliable that there are not many questions to ask about? I am also surprised that the dtplyr::lazy_dt(.) efficiency is not the default of all dplyr functions (where this is possible). Taken this all together my question is whether there any caveats about dtplyr one should know. What are possible drawbacks of using dtplyr::lazy_dt(.)?

Why dtplyr not a big thing: I am guessing the number of users who like tidy syntax but want dt efficiency is small. Users who are familiar with dt syntax would just use dt. Drawbacks: adding more dependency on packages.

"need to worry about speed" - sure, but most users don't have big enough data to worry about efficiency.

Yes, that is what I mean, for most data analysis, speed/efficiency is not important, as the data is not big enough to feel the efficiency of dt.

@zx8754 My data has 60k to 500k rows. Is this considered "big"?

It all depends, it's just my opinion. 500k, depending on what you do with it, any modern laptop would manage it without dt.

I usually use dtplyr when there's a calculation involving 10k+ groups, where it can give a good performance boost over dplyr. There are now a variety of dplyr wrappers that give you access not only to data.table, but also duckdb, arrow, and polars, all of which offer exceptional performance for larger data. https://outsiderdata.netlify.app/posts/2024-04-10-the-truth-about-tidy-wrappers/benchmark_wrappers

@JonSpring, and the incredible fast collapse package offering a similar and related syntax.

After working a bit with dtplyr::lazy_dt() I encountered problems which I want to share. Unfortunately, there are functions that are not compatible with lazy_dt(). See this example:
library(magrittr)

rnorm(100) %>%
  matrix(., ncol= 10) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(., nm= letters[1:10]) %>%
  dtplyr::lazy_dt() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(ab= a*b) %>%
  dplyr::reframe(ab_x= density(ab)$x,
                 ab_y= density(ab)$y)

This results in an error: Error in UseMethod("reframe") :  no applicable method for 'reframe' applied to an object of class "c('dtplyr_step_mutate', 'dtplyr_step')". So it works with dplyr::muate() but not with dpylr::reframe(). And there are other functions that won't work after lazy_dt(), like setNames(), for example.
This means one can not simply add lazy_dt() to the existing code and all runs smooth by itself. It depends what functions you use. This is a big drawback to me.

Do you see this error if you remove the dplyr:: namespace from mutate() and reframe() calls?

Exactly. You've found another answer to your first question. There are simply some dplyr verbs or functions that dtplyr can't handle. Another operation is bind_rows(). That function too won't work on objects created by lazy_dt. So, rather than discover issues like this partway through one's dtplyr-heavy workflow, some users like myself just begin scripting around another package entirely like data.table.
